# Trying to get 2 Plotly graphs to work independtly - not with Global variables

Tags: javascript, global-variables, plotly, local-variables

newbie here!

I'm using plotly to create graphs and currently have 2 graphs, however my variables are currently global variables and influencing each others graphs.

How can I best constrict the variables to only be locally accessible to the graph it pertains?

Plotly graphs use the variables data, layout, and config. But these values are different for each graph.

These are 2 independent graphs, INCOME PIE CHART and FIXED COSTS PIE CHART:

```
/* INCOME PIE CHART */
var data = [{
  values: [],
  labels: ['Salary', 'Bonuses', 'Gigs'],
  type: 'pie'
}];

var layout = {
    title: "Please enter data<br>above to graph",
    font: {size: 12},
    paper_bgcolor:"#ade7ba"
};

var config = {responsive: true}

Plotly.newPlot('incomePieChart', data, layout, config );

function incomePieChart() {
    var netSalaryPER =
        Number($("input#netSalary").val()) / 
        Number($("input#totalIncomeValue").val()) 
        * 100;
    var bonusSalaryPER =
        Number($("input#bonusSalary").val()) / 
        Number($("input#totalIncomeValue").val()) 
        * 100;
    var gigSalaryPER =
        Number($("input#gigSalary").val()) / 
        Number($("input#totalIncomeValue").val()) 
        * 100;
    data[0].values[0] = netSalaryPER;
    data[0].values[1] = bonusSalaryPER
    data[0].values[2] = gigSalaryPER
    /* TESTING PURPOSES USE THIS TO WRITE PERCENTAGES $("input#netSalaryPER").val(netSalaryPER); */
    layout.title = 'Income Overview';
    Plotly.newPlot('incomePieChart', data, layout, config );
}

/*FIXED COSTS PIE CHART*/
var data = [{
  values: [],
  labels: ["Home", "Transport", "Insurance", "Subscriptions", "Credit Card Payments"],
  type: "pie"
}];

var layout = {
    title: "Please enter data<br>above to graph",
    font: {size: 12},
    paper_bgcolor:"#ade7ba"
};


var config = {responsive: true}

Plotly.newPlot("fixedCostsPieChart", data, layout, config );

function fixedCostsPieChart() {
    var totalHomeCostValuePER =
        Number($("input#totalHomeCostValue").val()) / 
        Number($("input#totalFixedCostsValue").val()) 
        * 100;
    var totalTransportCostValuePER =
        Number($("input#totalTransportCostValue").val()) / 
        Number($("input#totalFixedCostsValue").val()) 
        * 100;
    var totalInsuranceCostValuePER =
        Number($("input#totalInsuranceCostValue").val()) / 
        Number($("input#totalFixedCostsValue").val()) 
        * 100;
    var totalSubscriptionCostValuePER =
        Number($("input#totalSubscriptionCostValue").val()) / 
        Number($("input#totalFixedCostsValue").val()) 
        * 100;
    var totalCreditcardCostValuePER =
        Number($("input#totalCreditcardCostValue").val()) / 
        Number($("input#totalFixedCostsValue").val()) 
        * 100;
    data[0].values[0] = totalHomeCostValuePER;
    data[0].values[1] = totalTransportCostValuePER;
    data[0].values[2] = totalInsuranceCostValuePER;
    data[0].values[3] = totalSubscriptionCostValuePER;
    data[0].values[4] = totalCreditcardCostValuePER;
    layout.title = "Fixed Costs";
    Plotly.newPlot("fixedCostsPieChart", data, layout, config );
}
```

Comment: Wrap the variables you want to be hidden from the outside world, in a function.

Comment: That's what I thought, just now I'm having trouble getting the 2nd incomePieChart to work... how can I access the the data in the first function from the second?

Comment: If data needs to be shared, pull it out of both functions, and supply it as an argument to them.